# in oracle select query how to add a number column increment by 2 starting from 1

Tags: oracle

i need to write a oracle select query where i need a additional column which increment by 2 starting from 1.

**Example:**

```
column1  column2 
amit      1
siva      3
pyll      5
```

here from oracle table i can get only column1. but in query i have to generate column2. So my issue is dynamically get a column like rownum() and increment it by 2. is there any way to get such result. in mysql we can use session variables inside a query. i expect a similar kind of solution in oracle. but i couldn't find a simple query to generate such numbers.

Comment: Does the order matter? Think about the number rownum would give you for each row, and then think how you would convert that number into the one you've shown - how you would do that manually to start with, and then think about how to translate that to SQL. You aren't incrementing anything exactly; you're manipulating the rownum value...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know you have rownum available, but take a step back. You're starting with the contiguous sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,... and you want to generate a sequence of odd numbers 1,3,5,7,9,11,.... So you need to figure out an algorithm that will convert one to the other.

If you say your starting number is `n` then you want to generate `m` where `m=(2*n)-1`.

You can use `rownum` (or `row_number()`, etc.) to generate your `n` values:

```
select column1, rownum as n
from your_table;
```

And you can then apply that algorithm:

```
select column1, (2*rownum)-1 as column2
from your_table;

COLUMN1    COLUMN2
------- ----------
amit             1
siva             3
pyll             5
jane             7
john             9
anna            11
...
```

With this simple approach the `column2` values are not in the same order as the `column1` values. You can either use `row_number()` or `rank()` instead, with a suitable `order by` clause; or use a subquery which does the ordering and apply rownum (and this algorithm) outside that:

```
select column1, (2*rownum)-1 as column2
from (
  select column1
  from your_name
  order by column1
);
```

or some other variation, depending on the result you want to end up with.